# how to make a over layout on system provided layout or dialog using kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile-application

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnbPE.png)
how to make a over layout on system provided layout or dialog using kotlin?
I want to show a transparent layout on  system provided layout or dialog using kotlin.
Because system provided layout should be seen behind transparent layout.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K49nI.png)